# Unable to get Child from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from a specific child node, but is unable to. 
I retrieved the barcode number from my listview from my previous activity. it is labelled "bc" in the code. As you can see i am able to retrieve the key from my previous activity in the database in a toast. I am unable to display anything in the respective `Textview` from the database.

Here is how i retrieve the barcode number(from the previous java activity):

```
mList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {

                 //   Object key= dataSnapshot.getKey();
                    String myKeys ;
                    myKeys = mList.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                    String bc = myKeys.split("Barcode:")[1];
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Inventory.this,Edit.class);
                    intent.putExtra("value",bc);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

[Pic of the Toast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMiYt.png)

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4cSZ.png) is a pic of my database:

**Here is my Activity:**

```
 public class Edit extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView Barcode,Pname,EntryDate,ExpiryDate,Quantity;
        DatabaseReference database;
        String bc = null;`



        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit);
            Barcode=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Barcode);
            Pname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Pname);
            EntryDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.EntryDate);
            ExpiryDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ExpiryDate);
            Quantity=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Quantity);
            bc = getIntent().getExtras().getString("value");
            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("All Barcodes");

            Toast.makeText(Edit.this,bc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            database.child(bc).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                      for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                          String barcode = (String) snapshot.child("barcode").getValue();
                      Log.d("TAG", barcode);

                          String pname = (String) snapshot.child("pname").getValue();
                          String date = (String) snapshot.child("date").getValue();
                          String expiration = (String) snapshot.child("expiration").getValue();
                          String quantity = (String) snapshot.child("quantity").getValue();
                          Barcode.setText(barcode);
                          Pname.setText(pname);
                          EntryDate.setText(date);
                          ExpiryDate.setText(expiration);
                          Quantity.setText(quantity);

                      }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getMessage());

                }
            });


        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your database security rules.

Comment: @MartinDeSimone it is set to true!

Comment: Your code is fine, what is the value of bc when you toast it?

Comment: The toast displays the barcode number that i  have selected from the listview, Eg, 123, etc etc. @MartinDeSimone

Comment: @MartinDeSimone i added a picture of the toast!

Comment: If you add this line of code inside the for loop from onDataChange(), `Log.d("TAG", barcode);` what does it print?

Comment: @AlexMamo I added it in in the loop(shown in the above code), but it displays nothing!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, add all the following declarations inside the onDataChange method:

```
TextView Barcode=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Barcode);
TextView Pname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Pname);
TextView EntryDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.EntryDate);
TextView ExpiryDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ExpiryDate);
TextView Quantity=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Quantity);
```

Your code should look like this:

```
database.child(bc).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        TextView Barcode=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Barcode);
        TextView Pname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Pname);
        TextView EntryDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.EntryDate);
        TextView ExpiryDate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.ExpiryDate);
        TextView Quantity=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Quantity);

        for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String barcode = (String) snapshot.child("barcode").getValue();
            String pname = (String) snapshot.child("pname").getValue();
            String date = (String) snapshot.child("date").getValue();
            String expiration = (String) snapshot.child("expiration").getValue();
            String quantity = (String) snapshot.child("quantity").getValue();
            Barcode.setText(barcode);
            Pname.setText(pname);
            EntryDate.setText(date);
            ExpiryDate.setText(expiration);
            Quantity.setText(quantity);

            Log.d("TAG", barcode);
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot Alex! But it still does not display any data!

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I added the full declaration, as it should be. Just remove them from other places. Should remain only there, in `onDataChenge()`. Does it work now?

Comment: I have done as you have instructed, but it still displays nothing! I have added the code when I retrieve the barcode into a toast(shown above). If that would help

Comment: No, won't help. You need to keep those lines only in that method. If there are also in other plece, you need to comment them. Have you tried in this way?

Comment: What I meant by " I have added the code when I retrieve the barcode into a toast " is to show you the code I used to get the data to the toast, The codes are from another java activity. And regarding the comment, I have done what you have instructed. I am using the code you have given me, but does not work!

Comment: The code is fine. The problem is that you are instantiating those fields outside `onDataChenge()` method. Do as explained above and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

try check if (dataSnapshot.exists()) before the for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) loop, it will wait for the datasnap exist then setText in the field you want